# Finding explicit imports for ghc's -Wmissing-import-lists

Tags: haskell, warnings, code-generation, ghc

GHC generates warnings when there are implicit imports (see below). The goal is to replace these with explicit imports. Is there an automated way to generated the list (instead of manually finding it in code)?

```
/Users/srid/code/slownews/backend/src/SlowNews/Main.hs:10:1: warning: [-Wmissing-import-lists]
    The module ‘Control.Exception’ does not have an explicit import list
   |
10 | import           Control.Exception
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/Users/srid/code/slownews/backend/src/SlowNews/Main.hs:13:1: warning: [-Wmissing-import-lists]
    The module ‘Control.Monad.IO.Class’ does not have an explicit import list
   |
13 | import           Control.Monad.IO.Class
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 6):

GHC has a `-ddump-minimal-imports` flag which will do the trick.

Comment: On how to use this flag to achieve the desired result: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32959693/55246

Answer (score 1):

There's an open pull request un `importify` tool which I'm working on. After this is done you will be able to convert implicit imports to explicit automatically:

https://github.com/serokell/importify/pull/82

Answer (score 0):

The [Haskell Tools](http://haskelltools.org) project has some nice looking tooling for that. Apparently it works in Atom but I couldn't get it to work with atom or atom-beta on macOS. However, it does work at the command line. I have [a simple example stack project set up](https://github.com/steshaw/ht-example). The `Main.hs` uses an explicit import list:

```
module Main where

import System.Environment

doMain = print =<< getEnvironment

main = doMain
```

BTW, I installed the Haskell Tools with:

```
$ stack install haskell-tools-daemon haskell-tools-cli fswatch
```

Then execute:

```
$ ht-refact -e 'ProjectOrganizeImports' .
```

Now git tells me that I have the following diff:

```
-import System.Environment
+import System.Environment (getEnvironment)
```

Check out the [Haskell Tools](http://haskelltools.org) website for an interactive example of how it should work in an editor. Looks like a very promising set of refactoring tools.